# Is there a way to relevel a variable using the original level positions?

Tags: r, levels, forcats

I have a variable with many very long factor names that are in alphabetical order instead of logical. Is there a way to relevel by position instead of variable name?

`f <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), levels = c("b", "c", "d", "a"))`
Instead of `fct_relevel(f, "b", "a")`
using level order to move the second (b) before the first (a) `fct_relevel(f, 2, 1)`?

Comment: do you mean `factor(x, unique(x))`?

Comment: No, I mean changing the order of the levels based on position instead of names.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from `f` :

```
forcats::fct_relevel(f, as.character(f[2]), as.character(f[1]))
#[1] a b c d
#Levels: b a c d
```